# Convert string to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

Input:

```
mystr = "100110"
```

Desired output numpy array:

```
mynumpy == np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

I have tried:

```
np.fromstring(mystr, dtype=int, sep='')
```

but the problem is I can't split my string to every digit of it, so numpy takes it as an one number. Any idea how to convert my string to numpy array?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`list` may help you do that.

```
import numpy as np

mystr = "100110"
print np.array(list(mystr))
# ['1' '0' '0' '1' '1' '0']
```

If you want to get numbers instead of string:

```
print np.array(list(mystr), dtype=int)
# [1 0 0 1 1 0]
```

Comment: It should be noted that for large inputs, **grc**'s first method using `np.fromstring('...', np.int8)` is _much_ faster. Creating a `list` from the (large) string is unnecessary.

Answer (score 31):

You could read them as ASCII characters then subtract 48 (the ASCII value of `0`). This should be the fastest way for large strings.

```
>>> np.fromstring("100110", np.int8) - 48
array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=int8)
```

Alternatively, you could convert the string to a list of integers first:

```
>>> np.array(map(int, "100110"))
array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

**Edit**: I did some quick timing and the first method is over 100x faster than converting it to a list first.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `ord('0')` instead of `48`. Better explicit than implicit.

Answer (score 13):

Adding to above answers, numpy now gives a deprecation warning when you use `fromstring`
`DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead`.
A better option is to use the [`fromiter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html). It performs twice as fast. This is what I got in jupyter notebook -

```py
import numpy as np
mystr = "100110"

np.fromiter(mystr, dtype=int)
>> array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])

# Time comparison
%timeit np.array(list(mystr), dtype=int)
>> 3.5 µs ± 627 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.fromstring(mystr, np.int8) - 48
>> 3.52 µs ± 508 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.fromiter(mystr, dtype=int)
1.75 µs ± 133 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```