# Extracting element of pandas array of type numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe `df` whose elements are **each** a whole numpy array. For example the 6th row of column `'x_grid'`:

```
>>> e = df.loc[6,'x_grid']
>>> print(e)

[-11.52616579 -11.48006112 -11.43395646 -11.3878518  -11.34174713
 -11.29564247 -11.24953781 -11.20343315 -11.15732848 -11.11122382
 -11.06511916 -11.01901449 ...
```

But I cannot use this as a numpy array as it is just given as a string:

```
>>> print(type(e))

<class 'str'>
```

How can I store a numpy array to a dataframe so it does not get converted to a string? Or convert this string back to a numpy array in a nice way?

Comment: It's worth noting that this DataFrame is loaded from a csv file, which is no doubt where the conversion to string happens. So I guess converting this string back to a numpy array would be the easier route.

Comment: Plus, there are no commas to seperate the elements in your array.

Comment: Look at the source text file.  This array is a quoted string, complete with`[]`,  Are there also `...`?  The original dataframe had these array items, and the only way to save such a df to a 2d csv format is turn the complex items into strings.  pandas used `str(item)`.  Where possible avoid saving such dataframes as csv.

Comment: This has come up a number times, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898099/convert-a-string-with-brackets-to-numpy-array.  `literal_eval` might have problems with your string because it is missing the commas that normally mark a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Erfan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9081267/erfan) and [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) for the suggestions that combined to answer this question.

The solution is that when setting an element of the dataframe I first convert the numpy array `x` to a list (so it is comma separated not space separated):

```
df = df.append({'x_grid': list(x)}, ignore_index=True)
```

Then after saving to a csv, and loading back in, I extract it back into a numpy array using `np.array()` and `ast.literal_eval()` (Note: requires `import ast`):

```
x = np.array(ast.literal_eval(df.loc[entry,'x_grid']))
```

This then returns a correct numpy array `x`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert all those strings in each row into a list the following will work:

```
df['x_grid'].str[1:-1].str.split(" ").apply(lambda x: (list(map(float, x))))

# or for a numpy array
df['x_grid'].str[1:-1].str.split(" ").apply(lambda x: (np.array(list(map(float, x)))))
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Want to extend Rafal's answer to avoid numpy throwing exception from empty strings resulting from the `x.split`:

```
df['x_grid'].str[1:-1].apply(lambda x: list(filter(None,x.split(' ')))).apply(lambda x: np.array(x).astype(np.float))
```