# How to convert a string to numpy array?

Tags: python, string, numpy

Converting string to numpy array

Given a string `abcxyz`, I want it to return a numpy array like:

```
array(["a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z"]).
```

I have tried `fromstring`

```
Bingrid = np.fromstring(elements, dtype=str)
```

but it returns

> ValueError: Zero-valued itemsize.

Comment: Try: `numpy.array(list("abcxyz"))`

Comment: `fromstring()` is for parsing a delimited list, like a CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list()`.

```
import numpy as np
s = "abcxyz"
print(np.array(list(s)))
```

Output:

```
['a' 'b' 'c' 'x' 'y' 'z']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case; if you do not want to convert into a list:

```
np.fromiter('abcxyz',(str,16))
#array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z'], dtype='<U16')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `np.array(list("abcxyz"))` ? No need for any special methods.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a list, then to an array:

```
import numpy as np
Bingrid = np.array(list("abcxyz"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

```
import numpy as np
mystr = "100110"
res =  np.array(list(mystr))
print(res)
```

Possible duplicate: [Convert string to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207743/convert-string-to-numpy-array)